# Java: How to force upcast?

Tags: java, kryo, kryonet

I'm using the Kryo library for serialization in Java. I have a problem where I have no way to force an upcast. Here is an example situation:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

public save() {
    Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
    kryo.setRegistrationRequired(true); //force registration
    kryo.register(A.class); //register A with kryo
    Output output = new Output( ... );

    B bar = new B();
    kryo.writeObject(output, (A) bar); //try to cast it up
}
```

This causes an `class not registered` error, because `bar` is still an instance of `B`.

Is there any way to force `bar` to be cast up to an instance of `A`, or will I need to do something like `new A(bar)`?

Comment: I think you mean to say 'because bar is still an instance of B'.

Comment: You have registered `A.class` so seems like you should be serializing an instance of `A`. Or if otherwise register `B.class`. You seem to be confused about the fact that upcast works on the reference to the instance not on the instance itself. It doesn't take an instance of `B` and produce and instance of `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upcasting doesn't change the object itself, only the type of the reference that points to it. You will have to register `B.class.`

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually do this since as you stated, casting does not change the fact that the object is still an instance of B, not A. You will need to make A delegate to a composite instance of B and pass it through the constructor as you suggested.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I had accidentally not removed that from my code, I've changed it now so it makes sense.

Comment: No worries, i saw that. I just changed my answer :)